# Why IntelliSense works in flat type and not in nested?

Tags: typescript, intellisense

I have complex but still not so complicated type which works like a charm when flat { uniqueIndex: string, uniqueValues: T } but when nested { index: { name: string, values: T } } the intellisense is suggesting all (not filtered) keys.

Typescript however correctly validates potential errors. It's **not critical as type validation works** as expected but it's ***annoying for the developer*** not to have the intellisense correct.

Does anybody why is this happening?

### Start of the code

```js
type IndexColumns<I extends string, Attrs extends Record<string, any>> = Record<
    I,
    Array<keyof Attrs>
>;

type CarIndexes =
    | "pk"
    | "brand_model"
    | "brand_category"
;

interface ICars {
    code: string;
    brand: "skoda" | "ford" | "volvo";
    category: "family" | "off-road" | "racing";
    model: string;
}

const carIndexColumns = {
    pk: ['code'],
    brand_category: ["brand", "category"],
    brand_model: ["brand", "model"],
} satisfies IndexColumns<CarIndexes, ICars>;
```

### Version 1 (flat = Intellisense working)

[playground](https://shorturl.at/eflA4)

```js
interface FindUniqueParams<Index extends CarIndexes> {
    context: 'tenant' | 'cross',
    uniqueIndex: Index,
    uniqueValues: { [K in (typeof carIndexColumns)[Index][number]]: ICars[K] }
}
```

### Version 2 (nested = Intellisense not working)

[playground](https://shorturl.at/ejpzN)

```js
interface FindUniqueParams<Index extends CarIndexes> {
    context: 'tenant' | 'cross',
    uniqueIndex: {
        name: Index,
        values: { [K in (typeof carIndexColumns)[Index][number]]: ICars[K] },
    }
}
```

### End of the code

```js
declare function findUnique<Index extends CarIndexes>(
    params: FindUniqueParams<Index>,
    arg?: { logging?: boolean },
): void;
```

Comment: I looked through GitHub and I couldn't find anything obviously related to this (there are plenty of "this intellisense completion list is wrong" issues, but apparently not ones like this).  It might be worthwhile for you to open a new (properly filed) issue in GitHub about it and then come back here to self-answer when it's been triaged.